# k-Nearest Neighbors where each point is its own class

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, knn

I'm trying to do recommendation based on feature similarity where my points in feature space represent unique classes. Essentially I have hundreds of unique items represented as low-dimensional feature vectors and I want to find the *k*-nearest neighbors in rank order for a new observation.

Conventionally you find the *k* neighbors and choose the class with the majority of representation therein. That won't work in my case considering each item has its own class.

Is *k*NN the wrong approach here? Is there a different family of algorithms more appropriate for this kind of problem?

Comment: So, you have multiple classes and your train set for each class is only one element?

Comment: @amit exactly. Potentially hundreds of classes where each class is only one element.

Comment: Well, machine learning algorithms usually need more than one item per class to work properly. I mean, you can go with NN (kNN with k=1), but I wouldn't call that machine learning in your case...

Comment: Yeah, I think in this case it's actually just computing the distance between your observation and all possible points in feature space and then sorting them?

Comment: Or put your observations in a [k-d tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree), and when a new instance comes, check for nearest neighbor in `O(logn)` time.

Comment: Thanks @amit -- But... if I approach the problem this way I can't say we're using machine learning! ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Whether kNN is the right approach boils down to whether your classes are well characterized by a distance metric in your feature space. There is nothing inherently wrong with what you are proposing. You can simply associate a unique class with each training observation and then apply kNN with `k = 1`.

Comment: Thanks @bogatron. If *k* is 1, how do I derive a ranking? I'm hoping to find the list of nearest classes in distance order

Comment: Ah. That's different. kNN isn't really about ranking classes. If you just wanted the nearest neighbor, you could use just about any canned kNN implementation. But if you want classes ranked, then I would just write a script to generate the distances to each training point (in descending order). The first item (least distance) corresponds to the kNN class (with `k = 1`) and the others will be the lesser ranked classes.

Comment: @bogatron I would guess, then, that you could not do a training and testing split, since there is only one example per class. How do we mitigate the lack of a testable split?

Comment: @spacedustpi A train/test split is pointless here because all it would do is remove classes from the "training" data (since there is only one example per class). To enable any actual learning (even in a lazy learner sense), you would either need multiple observations per class (assuming the different instances of a class don't all map to the same feature vector) or you would need some kind of truth data regarding the similarity of different classes/instances, though in the latter case, you would likely want to learn the feature embedding, rather than "learn" the kNN model.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to build a [recommender system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recommender_system), where you recommend new products based on a product already purchased. This is not a classification problem, and so you shouldn't be treating it like one.

What method to use really depends on more details about your data, the amount, the feature representation, and other issues. Recommender systems are often a harder problem them simple classification with more nuanced issues. [This coursera course](https://www.coursera.org/learn/recommender-systems) may be more helpful to you.

Comment: Yeah, I do want to do recommendation. The eventual goal is a sort of one-off recommendation based on survey responses. We don't have purchase (or any) history here (and this isn't a purchase). I'm aware of the literature on the topic, for the short term I was hoping to approach this as a classification problem as a sort of proof of concept that an ML-type approach could be useful here. Thanks!

Comment: @Raff.Edward the link is dead.